# My database contains fields with **special characters**. How can I read these characters?

Tags: php, json, database

My database contains fields with **special characters**. How can I read these characters? With the next code, Ma?? (Maçã) is returned.
Do I have this code:

```
$nome=$_POST['nome'];

$sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT idalimento, nome_pt FROM alimento WHERE 
nome_en= '$nome'");

while($exibe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo $exibe["nome_pt"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: ```echo utf8_encode($exibe["nome_pt"]), "<br>";``` might do the trick

Comment: How can i solve this?

Comment: your fields and your database in what encoding they are?

Comment: @BenGuest Finally it works! Thank you so much. For the next time, I'll ask right here. I've had a long time here. Thanks for your help :)